# How to add newline terminators to a .csv file that doesn't have any

Tags: bash, csv, unix

I have a very large `.csv` file (2 GB) on which running `file file.csv` returns `ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators`. I'm trying to split this large file into smaller files, but all the ways of doing this seem to rely on there being some standard kind of newline character, which my file doesn't have.

How can I add newline characters onto the end of the lines?

EDIT: I've tried using `unix2dos` to do this, but it doesn't do anything.

EDIT 2: Here is a `hexdump` of the first 128 bytes:

```
00000000  49 64 2c 55 73 65 6e 6e  61 6d 65 2c 44 61 74 65  |Id,Usenname,Date|
00000010  74 69 6d 65 50 6f 73 74  65 64 2c 54 61 67 55 73  |timePosted,TagUs|
00000020  65 64 34 32 2c 36 31 62  61 61 65 62 61 38 64 65  |ed42,61baaeba8de|
00000030  31 33 36 64 39 63 31 61  61 39 63 31 38 65 63 33  |136d9c1aa9c18ec3|
00000040  38 36 30 65 38 2c 32 30  30 34 2d 31 31 2d 30 34  |860e8,2004-11-04|
00000050  20 30 32 3a 32 35 3a 30  35 2e 33 37 33 37 39 38  | 02:25:05.373798|
00000060  2b 30 30 2c 65 63 6f 6c  69 34 32 2c 36 31 62 61  |+00,ecoli42,61ba|
00000070  61 65 62 61 38 64 65 31  33 36 64 39 63 31 61 61  |aeba8de136d9c1aa|
```

on line 3, there should be a line break in between `ed` and `42` and similarly, on line 7 there should be a break between `ecoli` and `42`. Does this output mean that this csv I've been given is actually just one long line?

Thanks

Comment: The question of "adding newline characters onto the end of lines" is a paradox. If you yourself can't define where a line ends, neither will any program you write.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - how can I figure out what the newline character is? The text editor doesn't show any

Comment: Well either it's either something foreign to your system, or they're really missing. You should look at the file with something proper, such as `vim` with `:set list` that will show most non-printable things. If you can't spot anything in the csv that could be a newline, you're...in a difficult position. You could still try to infer the structure from the csv itself, for instance if it has a header line than you can count the number of columns by hand, or search for a terminator in a more focused way...

Comment: Could be a lineending problem: the reading app expects other lineending as the file has. Can you convert lineendings from Unix to Windows convention and try again (make a backup before!)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak that sounds like a good workaround - there are 4 columns, delimited by `,` - is there any quick one liner that can add a specific newline character after every 4th column?

Comment: @LarsFischer tried doing this with `unix2dos`, with no luck :(

Comment: Use `hexdump` or `od` to dump the first 10K or so of the file. Take a look at how lines are delimited. You know they are delimited somehow, or you would have a one-line .csv file...

Comment: The quickest I can think of is `sed 's/,/,\n/g' infile | paste - - - -`. Hmm, still need to remove the final comma, but you can see my approach. One more `sed s/,$//'` or whatever.

Comment: I think something fishy is going on - did a `hexdump` - please see edited question. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: I'd say there is something fishy if there is no delimiter between `TagUsed` and the `Id` of `42`. The `Usenname` of `61baaeb...` suggests something went wrong when the .csv was created. How was the .csv created? Or `TagUsed42` is the first `Id` -- regardless there are No line delimiters. Are the lines a fixed length (I didn't count)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - so I was just given the file by someone who used it before me. The thing is that quite a few months ago, I did manage to somehow shove it into a SQLite database on my old laptop, from which I exported a small (5k rows) subset with which I'd been developing (a machine learning model) until now. I've lost the credentials to this database so have no idea how to access it now... currently redownloading the original .rar file I was given to see the original csv, perhaps it got corrupted somehow at some point

Comment: Correction - the original file I was given was a `.db` file itself, so I somehow messed up exporting the db to a csv I guess! Sorry to lead you all on this wild goose chase, turns out I'm just stupid! Will just set up the database again and export correctly this time...

Comment: Yes -- no problem, I'd go back to the original `.db` file and access it in whatever the native program is and try to re-export it. Good luck and keep the new tools close at hand.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - yes, thanks a lot - learned some nice little tricks :)